# Button dissapears when run in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

As the title suggests. Button is clearly present and visible in Android Studio. I run the emulator and it dissapears.
I have done numerous searches but cant seem to find a case-specific solution. Could you please take a look and see if you can spot something I cannot.

activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="154dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="581dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:text="SEARCH"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

MainActivity.Java:

```
private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openListActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openListActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The buttons sole purpose at the moment is to open a second activity.

Is there any other potentially relevant code I have missed?

Comment: Your button is confused. It doesn't know where to place itself. You are making it align start and end together. Also, how will a button go to the top of the screen as well as to the bottom at once? It's like I am at Moon and Earth at the same time.

Comment: You have a very large top margin '
        android:layout_marginTop="581dp"` . Maybe you are using an emulator with smaller screen size and it is off the screen? Could you please provide the full `activity_main.xml` and your emulator specs?

Comment: Start with only height and width. Then add needed properties one by one.

Comment: You were right, @Rohit5k2, I deleted some of the align statements and it appeared on the screen. Simple fix it seems. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your margin is too large for the button to render to an immulator or regular device. As you know, the margin is going to put space between your widget and other widgets on the screen. But spacing of that magnitude will force your image to disappear completely. I would reduce my margin and define a more practical layout as your project grows. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: This, along with the alignment issue highligted in the comments, fixed the problem. It seems the button was hanging at the bottom of the screen